# .Net Core Middleware for Logger

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, .net-core, middleware

I'm aware that there are a number of answers on Google about injecting middleware to log every request as it comes in, but I want something a little different. For every event that I log, I'd like to add some additional context from the request, like header information.

I know that I can extend the built in logger and use the HttpContextAccessor to update with the headers that I want. This needs to be added to the DI container as request scoped.

The problem is that I'd like to retain my services as singletons. I don't want to request scope them and have a new object created every time just in the event that I might want to log something.

Is there a way to intercept logging and add the headers and only have the logger request scoped? Or is there another approach that can be suggested that I'm not considering?

Comment: I would take a look at SeriLog and Enrichers.  You can add a custom enricher that will add data the data that you want to your Logging context and your Logger will remain a Singleton so I don't imagine it will clash with your Singleton services.  I recently half implemented something similar to what you have.  My services were scoped, but logging at my setup I don't see why Singleton services would cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. After much research, I came to that same conclusion myself and wrote a work item out to research it. I'm actually advocating Singleton services. I really don't know what the overhead of scoped services are, but why use them when a singleton will suffice?

Comment: Logically that does make sense.  I haven't looked into it much myself, from what I was seeing scoped was the recommended default unless you had a solid reason not to use it.  And my current projects have a small number of users so the small overhead wasn't something I was worried about.